# Problem installing roboearth (linux/videodev.h: no such file or directory)

Tags: roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to install the Roboearth Stack as described in its wiki ([Roboearth Wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roboearth). I am running Ubuntu 11.04 64-bit. I have installed ros-electric version. After updating my ros versions and installing all the dependencies, I ran rosmake roboearth. It was able to build 92 packages and failed on one. I am posting the output of the rosmake process:

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/5f739335931168902835410c92f3ef25

I searched a little bit and found this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842235/linux-videodev-h-no-such-file-or-directory-opencv-on-ubuntu-11-04
It seems to indicate a problem with opencv. I am not sure how to fix it so that I can get roboearth to compile. I already had libv4l-dev installed, so that wasn't the problem.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11748/problem-installing-roboearth-(linux/videodev.h:-no-such-file-or-directory)/) by [Sudarshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/291/sudarshan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2011-10-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a problem with ar_toolkit (not opencv, that should probably be patched already). See the wiki page for a fix: http://www.ros.org/wiki/artoolkit

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sudarshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/291/sudarshan/) on 2011-10-31**:
Thank you! That fix worked perfectly. Also, my apologies for wrongly accusing OpenCV.